# Why isn't the output of git branch and git branch -a the same?

Tags: git

```
[root@ test]$ git branch -a
* master
  origin
  remotes/origin/master
[root@ test]$ git branch
* master
  origin
```

IMO `origin` is remote and `master` is local, what's `remotes/origin/master` there for?

Comment: IMO, pointless question. You are adding a flag - `-a`, you should expect it to do something different and should read up the manual for `git branch`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git branch` shows only local branches, `git branch -a` shows all branches, including [remote-tracking branches](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#examining-remote-branches).

You've got local branches named `master` and `origin`.

`remotes/origin/master` is a remote-tracking branch for the `master` branch in the remote repository named `origin`.

Your local `master` *probably* tracks `remotes/origin/master`. From that output, you can't tell what's up with `origin`, but it's likely either a product of a mistaken command or simply a poorly-chosen branch name. (You can do `git branch -va` to get some more helpful information.)

Comment: It's worth being careful about saying things like "remotes/origin/master is the master branch in the remote named origin" - in fact it's a remote-tracking branch, which represents the state that `master` was in `origin` at the time of the last `git fetch` (or the last successful `git push` you did to `master` in `origin`, etc. etc.)

Comment: I've added some (very small) clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`origin` maybe a tracking branch for `remotes/origin/master`. But only `remotes/origin/master` is the remote.

You can try `git checkout remotes/origin/master`, it is a different branch.

Comment: How do I verify whether origin tracks remotes/origin/master or not?

Comment: Git doesn't have any aliases by default, so `git co` wouldn't work.

Comment: @asker, check `.git/config`. Under `[branch origin]` it should have a `remote=` line

Comment: @asker "gitk --all" can also help you visualize what's going on with your branches